# Issue with String using in multiple functions

Tags: rust

I'm a beginner with Rust, and I have small issues with String.
I have a struct like this :

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Config {
    pub filepath: String,
    #[serde(default = "default_port")]
    pub port: i16
}
```

I need `filepath` field in several methods using here :

```
pub fn startup(port: i16, filepath: String) -> () {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();
    server.get("/", middleware! { |request, mut response|
        routes::base::home(request, filepath)
    });
    routes::index_route(&mut server, filepath);

    let addr = format!("127.0.0.1:{}", port);
    println!("Start Rest Api successfully");
    server.listen(addr).unwrap();
}
```

Home is defined like this : `pub fn home(_request: &mut nickel::Request, path: String) -> String`

And index_route : `pub fn index_route(server: &mut Nickel, path_data: String) -> ()`

But I have this error : `use of moved value: filepath`
I've use to_owned or clone or to_string, and I don't understand why it doesn't work. I've read the book but I think something is missing

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What do I have to do to solve a "use of moved value" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800121/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-solve-a-use-of-moved-value-error)

Comment: It doesn't help me... Because  when i'm using a ref, I have this error : `explicit lifetime required in the type of `path_data``

Comment: The full error message should give you a pretty good explanation of the error. Please read it carefully – it's really your best source for hints what's wrong. You are moving `filepath` twice – first into `home()`, then into `index_route()`. If you control these functions, consider changing their signatures to use `&str` instead of `String`. If that's not in option, pass in a copy of the string in the call to `home()`, i.e. pass `filepath.clone()` instead of `filepath`.

Comment: i've tried to change all signatures with `&str`, but I have others errors ... 
If I "listen" the compiler, i need static lifetime, but when I change to static lifetime, others errors appears.
Maybe the `Config struct` is the issue?

There is the link to my repo :
https://github.com/Universemul/search_engine

It will be easier I think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clone the string *before* moving it into the closure:

```
pub fn startup(port: i16, filepath: String) -> () {
    let mut server = Nickel::new();

    let filepath_clone = filepath.clone();
    server.get("/", middleware! { |request, mut response|
        // use the clone from above
        routes::base::home(request, filepath_clone)
    });

    // the original is still accessible
    routes::index_route(&mut server, filepath);

    let addr = format!("127.0.0.1:{}", port);
    println!("Start Rest Api successfully");
    server.listen(addr).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've think about it before posting the issue but I didn't know if it was a "good" practice. 
By looking the source code of nickel, it's the only solution ...

Comment: I wasnt sure if this was considered good practice either! thanks for clearing that up