# How to resolve "use of moved value", "value moved here, in previous iteration of loop"?

Tags: rust

I wanna use *calamine* to read excel file.
First, get sheet names by **workbook**, then iterator all sheets to read it's content.
But, there is error when pass **workbook** to **handle_sheet** in **for**

source code:

```
use std::{fs::File, io::BufReader};
use calamine::{open_workbook_auto, DataType, Reader, Sheets};

pub fn read_to_workbook(filename: String) {
    let workbook = open_workbook_auto(filename).expect("Cannot open file");

    let sheets = workbook.sheet_names().to_owned();
    for sheet_name in &sheets {
        handle_sheet(sheet_name.to_string(), workbook);
    }
}

fn handle_sheet(sheet_name: String, mut workbook: Sheets<BufReader<File>>) {
    if let Some(Ok(range)) = workbook.worksheet_range(&sheet_name) {
        // ..do something
    }
}
```

error:
`error[E0382]: use of moved value: workbook`

I'm newbie in Rust, Thank you very much.

should I use reference **workbook** in handle_sheet?
or pass **workbook** 's clone to handle_sheet?
or create a new **workbook** in handle_sheet instead of pass it?

Answer (score 2):

In Rust when passing parameters, ownership is moved. Because of that your `workbook` would no longer accessible after the first iteration of the loop and the compiler will complain. For more information see https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-01-what-is-ownership.html

Passing the first parameter is no problem, because you create a new `String` each iteration with `to_string()`.

You could fix your problem by either passing `workbook` as a mutable reference or by cloning.

To pass as a mutable reference use `&mut workbook` instead of `workbook` when calling `handle_sheet`. Also change the workbook parameter to `workbook: &mut Sheets<BufReader<File>>`

If `workbook` was cloneable you could also use `workbook.clone()` when calling the function. See: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/clone/index.html

You might also want to take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800121/what-do-i-have-to-do-to-solve-a-use-of-moved-value-error?rq=1).